# Binary operator for different version of template class

Tags: c++, templates, operators

I have template class Point2D and I need to implement binary operator for diiferent version of template class. This code doesn't compile because of problem with `operator+`

```
template <class T>
class Point2D
{
public:
    T x;
    T y;
    Point2D(T _x=0,T _y=0):x(_x),y(_y)
    {
    }
    Point2D(Point2D& ob)
    {
        x=ob.x;
        y=ob.y;
    }
    template <class T1>
    Point2D(Point2D<T1>& ob)
    {
        x=ob.x;
        y=ob.y;
    }
};
template <class T>
Point2D<T> operator+(const Point2D<T>& ob1,const Point2D<T>& ob2)
{
    return Point2D<T>(ob1.x+ob2.x,ob1.y+ob2.y);
}
int main()
{
    Point2D<int> ob1(10,10);
    Point2D<double> ob2(20,20);
    Point2D<double> ob3=ob2+ob1;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to enable such feature `Point2D<double> ob3=ob2+ob1;` but compiler can't deduce right version of this operator
`Point2D<T> operator+(const Point2D<T>& ob1,const Point2D<T>& ob2)`
What should I change for making it work?

Answer (score 2):

Use two template parameters:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
Point2D<T1> operator+(const Point2D<T1>& ob1,const Point2D<T2>& ob2)
{
    return Point2D<T1>(ob1.x+ob2.x,ob1.y+ob2.y);
}
```

This is the minimal change to make the compiler happy.

However, as you can see, the type of the result is instantiated with `T1` as template argument type, which may not be desirable. So you need to choose the best type which is desirable for your work. And this involves some sort of metaprogramming.

In C++11, it is really easy, with trailing return type:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
auto operator+(const Point2D<T1>& ob1,const Point2D<T2>& ob2) -> Point2D<decltype(obj1.x+obj2.x)>
{
    typedef decltype(obj1.x+obj2.x) R;
    return Point2D<R>(ob1.x+ob2.x,ob1.y+ob2.y);
}
```

Get familiar with trailing-return-type here:

- [Alternative function syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use two different template arguments, like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
Point2D<T> operator+(const Point2D<T>& ob1, const Point2D<U>& ob2)
{
    return Point2D<T>(ob1.x+ob2.x,ob1.y+ob2.y);
}
```

Or with [`common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
Point2D<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>
operator+(const Point2D<T>& ob1, const Point2D<U>& ob2)
{
    return Point2D<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type>(
        ob1.x+ob2.x,ob1.y+ob2.y
    );
}
```

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX what explanation?